# improve jquery mobile responsiveness, convert onclick to vclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm coding an android app using jquery mobile and cordova(phonegap). I have been having some responsiveness issues and wanted to convert every onclick in my code to vclick.

The problem is, my html is dynamically injected into a page  from an ajax call eg when changing to new page. I read json returned.

eg :

```
var str="<a onclick='blah blah' href='#'>whatever</a>&nbsp;<a onclick='blah blah' href='#'>whatever2</a>"
$('#container').html(str).trigger('create');
```

I want a way to loop through the contents of #container for every element that has onclick='blah blah' and create a $('element').live("vclick", function (evt) {}); and then remove the onclick attribute.

can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps by using the [`pageChange`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) event?

```
$(document).bind("pagechange", function( event, ui ){
    $('a').each(function(index, element) {
        if (element.onclick) {
            $(element).on('vclick', element.onlick).removeAttr('onclick');
        }
    });​
});
```

Comment: what about if its not <a> but a button or input

Comment: then just change your selector from `$('a')` to `$('a, button, input')` or similar